# Find the biggest digit in number

Tags: python

So, I have to input a number and find the biggest digit in that number, so if the number is 2314 I want to get 4, my code so far:

```
a = input()

for x in a:
    i = int(x)
```

Comment: Yes, Im just a begginer

Answer (score 1):

Convert to a `string`, then get the `max`

```
a = 2314
max(str(a))
# output 4
```

Comment: @Reti43 I deleted it, I caught on to what you said. :P

Answer (score 1):

If your input is a number, you will want to first convert your input to a string and then convert each character back into an integer and take the max. You can easily use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to convert all characters to integers using [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) and then apply [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max).

```
maximum = max(int(x) for x in str(a))
```

For the sake of an example:

```
maximum = max(int(x) for x in str(415023))  # 5
```

If on the other hand, your input is a string, then just skip the conversion to a string.

```
maximum = max(int(x) for x in a)
```

## A More Robust Solution

All of these examples assume that you don't have any decimal points or negative signs in your number. If you do then you can explicitly ignore those.

```
maximum = max(int(x) for x in str(a) if x not in '.-')
```

As an example:

```
a = -15.93
maximum = max(int(x) for x in str(a) if x not in '.-')  # 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework, here is another simple answer. Since you are a beginner, didn't use `max()`.

```
a = input("number: ")
print (sorted(list(a))[-1])
```

Converted the input to a list first, then sorted it. Last number is the max. That `[-1]` is the last index of the list.

Comment: Why not use `max()`? That's what's pretty much his assignment. `max()` will also find the maximum value in O(n) time, but sorting has higher complexity.

Answer (score 0):

A `reduce` in `python2` might also work.

```
maximum = reduce(lambda acc, n: acc if acc > int(n) else int(n), "123131891", 0)
```